# Invisible Field Notation for using many2many hide field based on selected values

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a question about the invisible field
If I then have the following
Field: A00, 
Possible Values: red,blue, green, orange, purple
Selected Values: red,green, purple
Type: many2many

Field: B00

Type: many2one
B00 should be hidden when red and blue are selected in A00
This must also work when other colours are also selected (e.g red,blue,green,orange)

How would I create this correctly in the invisible attribute ?

Many thanks
Samuel

Answer (score 2):

is red, blue, the name of the many2many field? if it is then:

```xml
<field name="B00" attrs="{'invisible': [('A00.name', 'in', ('red','blue'))]}"/>
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```xml
<field name="B00" attrs="{'invisible': [('A00', 'in', ('red','blue'))]}"/>
```

I hope this help you ;)

Comment: Hi there, that didn't work. I just tried it! Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: you could try passing ids (even if it is static to know if it works)?

Comment: The other thing that I can think is to create a boolean auxiliary field that updates through the onchange of the many2many field and with that field you can create your attrs easily.